# "Untrusted Enterprise Developer" trying to install an enterprise build

Tags: ios, build, enterprise

When I download the enterprise build and try to launch it, in case of iOS 8 I get "Untrusted App Developer" with *trust* and *don't trust* options. But in case of iOS 9, I get only *Dismiss* option.

Is there any way by which I can show trust and dont trust option.(any setting in info.plist).?

Comment: Did my answer below solved your problem? if yes, please accept. If not, please comment!

Comment: NO. I cant install another app.

Answer (score 0):

Go to "General" "Profiles" and make the trust there.

**Tip**: If you install and uninstall your app many times, and don't want to "trust" each time, create another app and install it once and leave it installed. This way, the device already know that the distributer is "trusted", and will not ask you for trusting your "real" app again.